# Could we remove 'Products' from SO header?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

For some time now, there is a *Products* item in the Stack Overflow header.
I think it would be better to add that link in the 'Help center or other resources' menu.

Is there a particular reason to make that link so prominent ?

[image]

Comment: ...Obviously, Stack Overflow is trying to sell products.  How else are they going to keep the lights on?

Comment: Yeah, because the help center is such a great place for product discovery...

Comment: `$('div[role=menubar]>ol.list-reset').hide();` As with everything else, a bit more of jQuery makes it better.

Comment: TL;DR: ain't gonna happen (status-declined). Use uBlock or a userscript to delete the element if you don't want to see it. It also causes bugs on mobile, which they're highly aware of, but haven't fixed.

Answer (score 6):

It does seem strange to collapse the "Customers" and "Use cases" links under "Products" (to make space for the toolbar icons) rather than consolidate them all to another menu button, but then again, having two menu buttons would be even more confusing.

But in the first place, we (logged-in users) have *two menus* that share a lot of common links (like Teams and Jobs), which is the most confusing part of it all. I think the whole navigation needs a more thorough do-over than simply moving the Products link, or whatever it was that resulted in what we're looking at right now.

> I think it would be better to add that link in the 'Help center or other resources' menu.

What site that sells or promotes products does so under their help center? That's like suggesting to put Google search in their help center and expecting people to go there to do web searches instead of Google.com.

Comment: The relevant part of the link is obviously _other resources_ and there is already a _Products_ area in the footer, as other site like Google do. But I get it, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Anyway, [TamperMonkey](https://github.com/TGrif/TamperGrif/blob/master/We%20don't%20want%20products%2C%20just%20SO.user.js) script.